# Searching for occurence of a string in a comma delimited list

Tags: php

I have a comma separated list and in that list i am interested to know if a specific string that starts in a certain way is present.

```
$accounting = 'acc';
$str = 'loan,k,hi,588888,acc';

if (strpos($str, $accounting) === TRUE)
{
echo 'that contained accounting';
}
else{
echo 'nothing was found';
}
```

The code is giving me nothing is found.Does `strpos` work in a comma delimited list?.

Comment: `strpos($str, $accounting) === TRUE` --- in what cases do you think this expression will be `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does strpos work in a comma delimited list?.

No, it doesn't, because `$str` is not a list, it's just a string. You have to convert it to a list (=array) first:

```
$lst = explode(',', $str);
```

and then search this list:

```
if(in_array('acc', $lst)....
```

Your wording is a bit unclear, but if you're looking for a list element that *starts* with a specific string, it's more complicated:

```
 function has_element_that_starts_with($lst, $prefix) {
     foreach($lst as $item)
         if(strpos($item, $prefix) === 0) // note three ='s
              return true;
     return false;
 }
```

Another option is a regular expression:

```
if(preg_match("~(^|,){$acc}(,|$)~", $str)....
```

for partial strings:

```
if(preg_match("~(^|,){$acc}~", $str)....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right change === to ==. will work.

```
$accounting = 'acc';
$str = 'loan,k,hi,588888,acc';

if (strpos($str, $accounting) == TRUE)
{
echo 'that contained accounting';
}
else{
echo 'nothing was found';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use php `strstr()` ,  [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$accounting = 'acc';

$str = 'loan,k,hi,588888,acc';

if (strstr($str, $accounting) )
{
    echo 'that contained accounting';
}
else{
    echo 'nothing was found';
}
```

Comment: That would have worked if it was case-insensitive.Anyway,that's a good one.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong in at least two ways. First, since you're only checking for a string, `strstr` is a waste of time, you should use `strpos` (see the manual). Second, and more important, it doesn't treat your `$str` _as a list_ (test it with something like `"i,58"`). If you do want it to work this way, just fix your original code (`!==false` instead of `===true`).